# How were the previous prophets another religion?

Tags: history, islamic-basis, prophets

Today I was in a discussion about previous prophets before Mohammed. Then we asked ourselves: Judaism and Christianity came before Islam so the prophets before Islam started were of a different religion unless the Jews and Christians used the prophets 'stories' to change them and make a religion. Someone also said that the previous prophets were muslims but the people changed the religion to suit their lifestyle. So my question are: Before islam started, Were the previous prophets originally muslims? if so then why did the people change them to christians and jews?

Sorry if this all seems confusing. I am confused myself!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the religion has always been One, Islam
The very first human being, Adam, was also a muslim. 
Islam means submission to will of Allah (the Only true God). So you can say they might have used different names for same God, might have changed religion name, but it had always been islam. In Quran.

So it had been the same religion always, from Adam , to all prophets, till prophet Muhammad.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, Prophet Muhammed (s.w) didn't invent Islam. Prophet completed the Islam. He was the last messenger. He wasn't assigned with something new. The message was already given. But was corrupted. All the prophets came with same message. 
It was always the same region. People named it differently, that's all.

Answer (score 1):

Previous prophets and their true followers were Muslims.

> Or do you say that Abraham and Ishmael and Isaac and Jacob and the
>   Descendants were Jews or Christians? Say, "Are you more knowing or is
>   Allah ?" And who is more unjust than one who conceals a testimony he
>   has from Allah ? And Allah is not unaware of what you do.
>
> Abraham was neither a Jew nor a Christian, but he was one inclining
>   toward truth, a Muslim [submitting to Allah ]. And he was not of the
>   polytheists.

Neither the name or identity of "Jew" nor "Christian" is present in the Taurat and Injil, these names were invented later on.

Answer (score 0):

Were the previous prophets of another religion?
Divine religions are like educational foundations and courses that God has revealed to the prophets according to the level of insight and ability of people to learn and act.

In the time of Noah, people had very little knowledge and could not understand the religion of Islam, understand and act.
They were like first graders; For this reason, God chose a simple and primitive religion for them, so their religion was not perfect.

In the time of Prophet Ibrahim (pbuh) the level of awareness of the people increased and they could have a more complete religion. So the religion of Abraham was more complete than the religion of Noah. This process continued until the religions of Prophet Moses (pbuh) and Jesus (pbuh), until the time of the Prophet Muhammad (pbuh) the people of the world reached the point where they could receive the most perfect religion; For this reason, God the Merciful sent the religion of Islam to the people, which was the most perfect religion.
Because Islam was the most perfect religion, the previous prophets preached to their own people that another prophet would come after us, but Muhammad (PBUH) is the last prophet and no prophet will come after him.

Ref: https://www.hawzahnews.com/news/899244/%DA%86%D8%B1%D8%A7-%D8%AF%DB%8C%D9%86-%DA%A9%D8%A7%D9%85%D9%84-%D8%AF%D8%B1-%D8%B2%D9%85%D8%A7%D9%86-%D9%BE%DB%8C%D8%A7%D9%85%D8%A8%D8%B1%D9%87%D8%A7%DB%8C-%D9%82%D8%A8%D9%84%DB%8C-%D9%86%DB%8C%D8%A7%D9%85%D8%AF-%D9%88-%D8%A7%D8%B3%D9%84%D8%A7%D9%85-%DA%A9%D8%A7%D9%85%D9%84-%D8%AA%D8%B1%DB%8C%D9%86-%D8%AF%DB%8C%D9%86