# What was religion of Adam (A.S)?

Tags: prophet-adam, religion

I was wondering what was religion of Adam(A.S) but I haven't got any information about this topic.

Comment: [How were the previous prophets another religion?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/55070/how-were-the-previous-prophets-another-religion) is relevant if not covering the topic of your question.

Comment: Yeah I got it. Thank you brother

Comment: I assume the duplicate answers your question!